# Crop an image in PIL using the 4 points of a rotated rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have a list of four points of a rotated rectangle in the form of:

```
points = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], [x4, y4]]
```

I can crop in PIL using:

```
img.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2))
```

But this doesn't work with a rotated rectangle. Just to clarify I want the resulting cropped image to be rotated so the cropped area becomes a non-rotated rectangle.

I am willing to use openCV, although would like to avoid it as the conversion of an image from PIL to openCV takes time, and I will be itterating through this process about 100 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start with this image:

[image]

You can do it like this using a [QuadTransform](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/PIL.html#module-PIL.ImageTransform):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageTransform

# Open starting image and ensure RGB
im = Image.open('a.png').convert('RGB')

# Define 8-tuple with x,y coordinates of top-left, bottom-left, bottom-right and top-right corners and apply
transform=[31,146,88,226,252,112,195,31]
result = im.transform((200,100), ImageTransform.QuadTransform(transform))

# Save the result
result.save('result.png')
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you so much! I assume that the (200, 100) is the length and width and height of the output image. I imagine that these values could be calculated by x = ((transform[2]-transform[0])**2+(transform[3]-transform[1])**2)**0.5 and y = ((transform[6]-transform[4])**2+(transform[7]-transform[5])**2)**0.5

Comment: @Yetiowner Yes, I think that's correct. I knew the dimensions of the magenta rectangle because I created it and rotated it, but assumed you could work out the lengths exactly as you did. Top work